# Thread Joining or Thread suspending\resuming in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In windows form application, I am creating a thread for some work and in between if your clicks for some other work, then I need to suspend earlier thread and need to do new task(high priority) first and after its completion, resuming  suspended one.  I have a timer to check for thread states, so I can manage processing.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can benefit from using thread signalling mechanisms such as for example the [AutoResetEvent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thread Synchronization events is the way to go for this particular scenario.  It's the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you manage this just by setting the priority of the background thread lower than that of the thread that manages the UI? Don't reinvent the wheel...

Comment: its working, but it looks slow, so I don't want to slower one to go and want to make it suspend for the time the new one executes